# Ubuntu 14.04.2 Handbrake 0.10.2

Tags: handbrake

I like to make some copies from my DVD else I'm afraid my kids could destroy them they sometimes play with them and when it comes to scratches.... When coming to that point I tried to use Handbrake 0.10.2 but unfortunately when I start the process nothing happen after the DVD scan is done.

Hope anyone do have an idea what I have to do.

Please find the log below:

```
[22:23:02] gtkgui: HandBrake 0.10.2 (2015061000) - Linux x86_64 - https://handbrake.fr
[22:23:03] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[22:23:03] hb_init: starting libhb thread

(ghb:4826): Gdk-WARNING **: gdk_window_set_icon_list: icons too large
[22:26:36] CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T9400  @ 2.53GHz
[22:26:36]  - logical processor count: 2
[22:26:36] hb_scan: path=/media/snofla/ICE_AGE_2_SE_D1/VIDEO_TS, title_index=0
libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening /media/snofla/ICE_AGE_2_SE_D1/VIDEO_TS/BDMV/index.bdmv
libbluray/bdnav/index_parse.c:162: indx_parse(): error opening /media/snofla/ICE_AGE_2_SE_D1/VIDEO_TS/BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
libbluray/bluray.c:2182: nav_get_title_list(/media/snofla/ICE_AGE_2_SE_D1/VIDEO_TS) failed
[22:26:36] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
libdvdnav: Using dvdnav version 5.0.1
libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sr0 mounted on /media/snofla/ICE_AGE_2_SE_D1 for CSS authentication
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2

libdvdread: Attempting to retrieve all CSS keys
libdvdread: This can take a _long_ time, please be patient

libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB at 0x0001ca70
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.VOB (0x0001ca70)
libdvdread: Elapsed time 3
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB at 0x0003bd26
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_0.VOB (0x0003bd26)
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB at 0x0004fa8a
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_01_1.VOB (0x0004fa8a)!!
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_02_1.VOB at 0x002aa3e9
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB at 0x002aca58
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_03_1.VOB (0x002aca58)!!
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB at 0x002b1688
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_04_1.VOB (0x002b1688)!!
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB at 0x002b4fac
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_05_1.VOB (0x002b4fac)!!
libdvdread: Elapsed time 1
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_06_1.VOB at 0x002ba58b
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_07_1.VOB at 0x002ced15
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_08_1.VOB at 0x002d9bf9
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Get key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_1.VOB at 0x002e4ae0
libdvdread: Error cracking CSS key for /VIDEO_TS/VTS_09_1.VOB (0x002e4ae0)!!
libdvdread: Elapsed time 0
libdvdread: Found 9 VTS's
libdvdread: Elapsed time 4
libdvdread: Attempting to use device /dev/sr0 mounted on /media/snofla/ICE_AGE_2_SE_D1 for CSS authentication
[22:26:40] scan: DVD has 13 title(s)
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 1
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 1
[22:26:40] dvd: Skipping multi-angle cells 0-1
[22:26:40] dvd: Skipping multi-angle cells 2-3
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 01:20:08 (4808840 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc019330
[22:26:40] scan: vts=1, ttn=1, cells=0->29, blocks=0->2468144, 2138770 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x81bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x8abd, lang=Deutsch (DTS), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x83bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=3
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x84bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=4
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x21bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x22bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x23bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x24bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x25bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 1 has 24 chapters
[22:26:40] dvd: Skipping multi-angle cells 0-1
[22:26:40] dvd: Skipping multi-angle cells 2-3
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->4, b=0->209329 (208382), 362880 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=5->5, b=209330->244302 (34973), 79920 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 3 c=6->6, b=244303->321554 (77252), 175280 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 4 c=7->7, b=321555->437731 (116177), 266480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 5 c=8->8, b=437732->495266 (57535), 133960 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 6 c=9->9, b=495267->534986 (39720), 96120 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 7 c=10->10, b=534987->593852 (58866), 132120 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 8 c=11->11, b=593853->633433 (39581), 89520 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 9 c=12->12, b=633434->736479 (103046), 227840 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 10 c=13->13, b=736480->820018 (83539), 192200 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 11 c=14->14, b=820019->952544 (132526), 299760 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 12 c=15->15, b=952545->1031075 (78531), 176320 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 13 c=16->16, b=1031076->1116668 (85593), 209160 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 14 c=17->18, b=1116669->1196221 (79553), 194640 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 15 c=19->19, b=1196222->1241930 (45709), 110240 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 16 c=20->20, b=1241931->1302372 (60442), 146680 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 17 c=21->21, b=1302373->1393664 (91292), 217600 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 18 c=22->22, b=1393665->1516822 (123158), 282760 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 19 c=23->23, b=1516823->1571067 (54245), 122160 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 20 c=24->24, b=1571068->1677781 (106714), 234360 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 21 c=25->25, b=1677782->1818961 (141180), 313560 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 22 c=26->26, b=1818962->2077663 (258702), 592440 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 23 c=27->28, b=2077664->2139665 (62002), 152360 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 24 c=29->29, b=2468093->2468144 (52), 480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 2
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 1
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:06:45 (405000 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 2, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc01a670
[22:26:40] scan: vts=1, ttn=2, cells=0->2, blocks=2468093->2305154, 165541 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x81bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x8abd, lang=Deutsch (DTS), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x83bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=3
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x84bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=4
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x21bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x22bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x23bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x24bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x25bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 2 has 3 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=2468093->2468144 (52), 480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=2139666->2304904 (165239), 403920 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 3 c=2->2, b=2304905->2305154 (250), 600 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 3
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 1
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:06:45 (405000 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 3, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc026b10
[22:26:40] scan: vts=1, ttn=3, cells=0->2, blocks=2468093->2468092, 162990 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x81bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x8abd, lang=Deutsch (DTS), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x83bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=3
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x84bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=4
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x21bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x22bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x23bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x24bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x25bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 3 has 3 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=2468093->2468144 (52), 480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=2305155->2467845 (162691), 403920 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 3 c=2->2, b=2467846->2468092 (247), 600 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 4
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 2
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:00:27 (27320 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc0206d0
[22:26:40] scan: vts=2, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->9824, 9825 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 4 has 2 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->9772 (9773), 26840 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=9773->9824 (52), 480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 5
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 3
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:01:00 (60480 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc021510
[22:26:40] scan: vts=3, ttn=1, cells=0->2, blocks=0->19489, 19490 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x85bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 7
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch (Closed Caption), 3cc=deu ext=5
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch (Closed Caption), 3cc=deu ext=5
[22:26:40] scan: title 5 has 3 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->19406 (19407), 59360 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=19407->19437 (31), 640 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 3 c=2->2, b=19438->19489 (52), 480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 6
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 4
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:00:45 (45400 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc01bb10
[22:26:40] scan: vts=4, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->14613, 14614 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=Unknown (AC3), 3cc=und ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 6 has 2 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->14403 (14404), 44400 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=14404->14613 (210), 1000 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,33333
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 7
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 5
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:01:08 (68600 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc01c5b0
[22:26:40] scan: vts=5, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->21967, 21968 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x85bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 7 has 2 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->21946 (21947), 68000 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=21947->21967 (21), 600 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,33333
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 8
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 3
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:01:00 (60480 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 2, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc0285c0
[22:26:40] scan: vts=3, ttn=2, cells=0->2, blocks=0->19489, 19490 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x85bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 7
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x86bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch (Closed Caption), 3cc=deu ext=5
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch (Closed Caption), 3cc=deu ext=5
[22:26:40] scan: title 8 has 3 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->19406 (19407), 59360 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=19407->19437 (31), 640 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 3 c=2->2, b=19438->19489 (52), 480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 9
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 1
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:06:45 (405000 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 4, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc06e130
[22:26:40] scan: vts=1, ttn=4, cells=0->2, blocks=2468093->2468092, 162990 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x81bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x8abd, lang=Deutsch (DTS), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x83bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=3
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x84bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=4
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x21bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x22bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x23bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x24bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x25bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 9 has 3 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=2468093->2468144 (52), 480 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=2305155->2467845 (162691), 403920 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 3 c=2->2, b=2467846->2468092 (247), 600 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 10
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 6
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:05:21 (321600 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc028d30
[22:26:40] scan: vts=6, ttn=1, cells=0->3, blocks=0->83833, 83834 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x85bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 10 has 4 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->26199 (26200), 98920 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=26200->58970 (32771), 117560 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 3 c=2->2, b=58971->83781 (24811), 104520 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 4 c=3->3, b=83782->83833 (52), 600 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,77778
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 11
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 7
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:00:40 (40280 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc06ed80
[22:26:40] scan: vts=7, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->14247, 14248 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 11 has 2 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->11851 (11852), 33520 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=11852->14247 (2396), 6760 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,33333
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 12
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 8
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:00:40 (40280 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc074a10
[22:26:40] scan: vts=8, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->14248, 14249 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x80bd, lang=English (AC3), 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: duplicate audio track
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 12 has 2 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->11851 (11852), 33520 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=11852->14248 (2397), 6760 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,33333
[22:26:40] scan: scanning title 13
[22:26:40] scan: opening IFO for VTS 9
[22:26:40] scan: duration is 00:00:22 (22000 ms)
[22:26:40] pgc_id: 1, pgn: 1: pgc: 0x7f05cc06ed60
[22:26:40] scan: vts=9, ttn=1, cells=0->1, blocks=0->7054, 7055 blocks
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 1
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 2
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 3
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 4
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 5
[22:26:40] scan: audio channel is not active
[22:26:40] scan: checking audio 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x85bd, lang=Deutsch (AC3), 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 1
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=English, 3cc=eng ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 2
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 3
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 4
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Turkish, 3cc=tur ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 5
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: checking subtitle 6
[22:26:40] scan: id=0x20bd, lang=Deutsch, 3cc=deu ext=0
[22:26:40] scan: title 13 has 2 chapters
[22:26:40] scan: chap 1 c=0->0, b=0->7033 (7034), 21400 ms
[22:26:40] scan: chap 2 c=1->1, b=7034->7054 (21), 600 ms
[22:26:40] scan: aspect = 1,33333
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:40] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:40] scan: decoding previews for title 1
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:40] scan: title angle(s) 2
[22:26:40] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
[22:26:40] Last error repeated 2 times
[22:26:40] dvd: dvdnav_sector_search failed - New position not yet determined.
[22:26:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
[22:26:40] scan: decoding previews for title 1
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:40] scan: title angle(s) 2
[22:26:40] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading NAV packet.
[22:26:40] dvd: dvdnav_sector_search failed - New position not yet determined.
[22:26:40] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
[22:26:40] scan: decoding previews for title 2
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:40] scan: title angle(s) 1
[22:26:40] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (2ae20000)
[22:26:41] dvdnav: Read Error, Error reading from DVD.
[22:26:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
[22:26:41] scan: decoding previews for title 2
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:41] scan: title angle(s) 1
[22:26:41] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (2ae20000)
[22:26:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
[22:26:41] scan: decoding previews for title 3
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:41] scan: title angle(s) 1
[22:26:41] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (2ae20000)
[22:26:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
[22:26:41] scan: decoding previews for title 3
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:41] scan: title angle(s) 1
[22:26:41] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (2ae20000)
[22:26:41] Warning: Could not read data for preview 1, skipped
[22:26:41] scan: decoding previews for title 4
libdvdnav: DVD disk reports itself with Region mask 0x00fd0000. Regions: 2
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead
libdvdnav: Menu Languages available: ÿÿ 
[22:26:41] scan: title angle(s) 1
[22:26:41] hb_demux_ps: not a PS packet (2ae20000)
```

Comment: May be that the dvd has structure protection that handbrake can't deal with or may be that your drive drive doesn't have a region set. Can you play the dvd in Ubuntu? Also note that handbrake does not create a file that can be burned to a dvd for an external dvd player..

Comment: No until now I wasn't able to get the DVD running even I use VLC.

Comment: Perhaps its a bad DVD scratched or something, did you try another DVD? Also try using another program to rip the video_ts and audio_ts folders then point handbrake to that Directory. If no copy protection you can just copy, if not you need a program. and as doug said, you can only rip to MP4 and MKV, not dvd formats, but they can play in most Game consoles. MP4 is more universally standard.

Comment: here is the same issue in Ubuntu 16.04 :(

Answer (score 3):

This could be the culprit:

```
libdvdnav: Language 'en' not found, using 'ÿÿ' instead`
```

I had a similar problem trying to rip a European dvd. Selecting the titles I needed and disabling dvdnav  worked for me (using the `--no-dvdnav` option mentioned [in this link](https://trac.handbrake.fr/wiki/CLIGuide)).

```
HandBrakeCLI --no-dvdnav \
            -i PATH-to/VIDEO_TS -t TITLE \
            -o PATH-to/OUTPUT.mp4 -e x264 -q 20 -B 160
```

This being said, I could open the disk with a recent version of vlc .
Anyway, hope this will spare someone some trouble!

Comment: this is a good workaround, thx a lot; 
a useful info: use "--title 0" option to detect the required information as title(s), audio track(s), subtitle track(s); 
and a possible command: 
`HandBrakeCLI --no-dvdnav -i source_path/VIDEO_TS/ -o destination_path.mkv --audio 2 --aencoder copy:mp3 --subtitle "2,3"`